# Access from external function to scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a problem with the external function `OnLoginFail` when invoking the function `showFormAndHideMessage` from it.
I try using

```
 angular.element($("login")).scope().showFormAndHideMessage().$digest();
```

but it doesn't not work. I understand that `scope()` should give me access to controller in directive.

Login.js

```
  lobby.directive( 'login', function() {
    return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: false,
    templateUrl: 'lobby/login/login.html',
    scope: {},

         ....

    function OnLoginFail( error ) {
       alert( error.Message );
       angular.element($("login")).scope().showFormAndHideMessage().$digest();  

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope only gives you direct access to parent scope if you aren't creating an isolate scope in your directive. You are isolating your scope in your directive with the following line:

```
scope: {}
```

**EDIT**

Per JPRO's comment, to fix this just delete that line in your directive's configuration.

Comment: Helpful to mention that to fix this you can delete the scope: {} or doing scope: false